# How do I condense a data frame to be wider while maintaining row inputs as row inputs and not column names in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot

I am currently working on a data project and need to condense the data so that the names in the data frame do not repeat. The issue is that names are repeated in the data frame because each name can have more than one ID code. Below I have attached a sample data frame:

```r
df_have <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Maya", "Maya", "Sierra", "Sophia", "Sophia", 
           "Sophia", "Cecilia", "Cecilia"),
  ID = c(24, 56, 54, 12, 15, 24, 12, 11)
)

df_have
#>      Name ID
#> 1    Maya 24
#> 2    Maya 56
#> 3  Sierra 54
#> 4  Sophia 12
#> 5  Sophia 15
#> 6  Sophia 24
#> 7 Cecilia 12
#> 8 Cecilia 11
```

And here is the sample transformed into the desired format:

```r
df_want <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Maya", "Sierra", "Sophia", "Cecilia"),
  ID1 = c(24, 54, 12, 12),
  ID2 = c(56, 0, 15, 11),
  ID3 = c(0, 0, 24, 0)
)

df_want
#>      Name ID1 ID2 ID3
#> 1    Maya  24  56   0
#> 2  Sierra  54   0   0
#> 3  Sophia  12  15  24
```

I am using R to transform the data. I have tried the pivot_wider command but have only been able to use it to transform the data into a data frame where the values in the column "ID" become the column names and the values in those columns are a dummy variable for whether or not the name has the corresponding ID number. This is not desired because there are too many ID codes for this to make the data useable (the data above is just an example). Aditionally, it did not solve the problem of the same name having multiple rows, as it just made the data frame wider without condensing it.

Comment: Please don't post images of data, but instead post your data as text. At least two people have had to transcribe your data from the picture to attempt to get code to work, whereas it would have been far simpler if you had included the data as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this perhaps? This starts by giving an `idno` counting up number of valid IDs in long dataframe and then using these numbers to create unique columns:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ids <- read_table("
            Name ID
            Maya 24
            Maya 56
            Sierra 54
            Sophia 12
            Sophia 15
            Sophia 24
            Cecilia 12
            Cecilia 11")

ids |>
  mutate(idno = row_number(), .by = Name) |>
  pivot_wider(
    values_from = ID,
    names_from = idno,
    values_fill = 0,
    names_prefix = "ID"
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   Name      ID1   ID2   ID3
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Maya       24    56     0
#> 2 Sierra     54     0     0
#> 3 Sophia     12    15    24
#> 4 Cecilia    12    11     0
```